# DTD: add an external image to your xml using CSS

Tags: css, xml, xslt, dtd

I have a simple xml file which conforms to the DTD. I'm using NOTATION in the DTD as below. I'm unable to fetch the file from the system with the below CSS code. Please let me know if my syntax is correct.

DTD

```
<!-- image notation -->
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST img src CDATA #IMPLIED> 
<!ENTITY logo SYSTEM "logo.gif" NDATA gif>
<!NOTATION gif PUBLIC "gif viewer">
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipes SYSTEM "Re.dtd" >
<?xml-stylesheet href="re.css" type="text/css"?>
<recipes>
   <recipe recipeID="recipe1">
     <title>Broccoli</title>
     <author>Scott</author>
     <img src="logo.gif"/>
   </recipe>
</recipes>
```

CSS

```
img {
background-image: url("chickenLinguine.gif");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The `xml-stylesheet` pi only applies to html documents. Not xml documents.

Comment: Also the NOTATION should be declared before referencing it. You did it in the wrong order.

Comment: I assume that that is not your entire DTD entity. Please show the entire DTD entity.